# using vtkTimerCallback with QVTKRenderWindowInteractor not working

Tags: python, callback, pyqt, vtk

Ive got a problem with vtk (8.1), pyqt5 (5.10.1). If I use the vtkCallBackTimer with the "original" **vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()** its all working fine. But if I use the **vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor()** the callback function is executed successively with no pause. Here is the example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import vtk
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class vtkTimerCallback():
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer_count = 0

    def execute(self, obj, event):
        print(self.timer_count)
        self.actor.SetPosition(self.timer_count, self.timer_count, 0)
        iren = obj
        iren.GetRenderWindow().Render()
        self.timer_count += 1

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super (ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        sphereSource = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
        sphereSource.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        sphereSource.SetRadius(5)
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(sphereSource.GetOutputPort())
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)
        renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
        renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
        renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor # <-- WOKRING
        renderWindowInteractor = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame) # <-- NOT WORKING (self.frame is a QFrame in the mainwindow.ui)
        renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)
        renderer.AddActor(actor)
        renderer.SetBackground(1, 1, 1)  # Background color white
        renderWindow.Render()
        renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()
        cb = vtkTimerCallback()
        cb.actor = actor
        renderWindowInteractor.AddObserver('TimerEvent', cb.execute)
        #****************
        renderWindowInteractor.CreateRepeatingTimer(1000) #Pause between new function call in millisecs,
        # with the QVTKRenderWindowInteractor the pause is ignored ?????
        #****************
        renderWindowInteractor.Start()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    trudeUI = ExampleApp()
    trudeUI.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

I hope anyone can help. I need the RepeatingTimer for an animation. If sb. has an alternative would be ok, but not the QtCore.QTimer, please. Should be a vtk-thing...
I trying this for 4 hours now, any help is welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same problem. As deep as I looked it appears to be a bug comming from `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` class. 
While creating the repeating timer, the duration parameter (1000 in your example) is not taken into account and the default parameter (10) is used instead.

So to fix it I created a subclass `MyQVTKRenderWindowInteractor` and overwrote the methods I needed:

```
class MyQVTKRenderWindowInteractor(QVTKRenderWindowInteractor):
   def __init__(self, *arg):
       super(MyQVTKRenderWindowInteractor, self).__init__(*arg)
       self._TimerDuration = 10 # default value

   def CreateTimer(self, obj, event):
       self._Timer.start(self._TimerDuration) # self._Timer.start(10) in orginal

   def CreateRepeatingTimer(self, duration):
       self._TimerDuration = duration
       super(MyQVTKRenderWindowInteractor, self).GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor().CreateRepeatingTimer(duration)
       self._TimeDuration = 10
```

Now `renderWindowInteractor = MyQVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)` should work.

Hopping answer has not come to late
++

Comment: Do you also observe that the timer stops if one clicks inside the render window? (See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285797)).